# How to set different colors for button in one css class

Tags: html, css

here is my html code. We have 4 buttons in one div with "TimeslotControlButton" css class for all buttons.

```
       <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtons">
        <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
            <asp:Button ID="btnNewCustomer" runat="server" Text="New Customer" meta:resourcekey="btnNewCustomerResource" CssClass="TimeSlotControlButton" onclick="btnNewCustomer_Click"  />
        </div>
        <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
            <asp:Button ID="btnCustomerSearch" runat="server" Text="Customer Search" meta:resourcekey="btnCustomerSearchResource" CssClass="TimeSlotControlButton"/>
        </div>
        <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
            <asp:Button ID="lnkFirstAvailable" runat="server" Text="First Available Time" meta:resourcekey="lnkFirstAvailableResource" CssClass="TimeSlotControlButton" style="float:left;"/>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSummary" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnSummaryResource" CssClass="TimeSlotControlButton" OnClientClick="popupSummary.Show(); return false;" />
        </div>
        <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
            <asp:Button ID="lnkPreviousStep" runat="server" Text="Previous 
       Step" meta:resourcekey="lnkPreviousStepResource"  
       CssClass="TimeSlotControlButton" onclick="lnkPreviousStep_Click" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>

and this is my css class:

        .TimeSlotControlButton {
            background-color: #AC2430;
            border: 2px solid #AC2430;
            color: white;
            height: 29px;
            padding: 0 20px;
        }
```

So i need to change button background for button with ID="lnkFirstAvailable" to grey color.
And button with ID="btnSummary" to black color.
But i can't change html file, can only css

Comment: Can you provide your html code.

Comment: is your html always the same ? ( same classes and id's ) ? or do those change dinamicaly ? if they don't change, just write more specific css path like `.TimeSlotControlBlockButtons .TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv #lnkFirstAvailable { background-color:grey } `

Answer (score 1):

Use simple css ID selector to set `background-color` as like below

```
#lnkFirstAvailable{
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Or do be more specific use id-class combination as below

```
#lnkFirstAvailable.TimeSlotControlButton{
   background-color: grey;
}
```

```css
.TimeSlotControlButton {
  background-color: #AC2430;
  border: 2px solid #AC2430;
  color: white;
  height: 29px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#btnNewCustomer {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtons">
  <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
    <input type="button" id="btnNewCustomer" value="First Button" class="TimeSlotControlButton">
  </div>
  <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
    <input type="button" id="btnCustomerSearch" value="First Button" class="TimeSlotControlButton">
  </div>
  <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
    <input type="button" id="lnkFirstAvailable" value="First Button" class="TimeSlotControlButton">

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
    <input type="button" id="btnSummary" value="First Button" class="TimeSlotControlButton">
  </div>
  <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
    <input type="button" id="lnkPreviousStep" value="First Button" class="TimeSlotControlButton">
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It must work, check the updated fiddler. what you are getting actually?

Comment: It's show that my css file was loaded, but 
button use only 
          .TimeSlotControlButton {
  background-color: #AC2430;
  border: 2px solid #AC2430;
  color: white;
  height: 29px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
} 
css style

Comment: If you are using **asp.net usercontrols**, your `id` will be dynamic and will add usercontrol name with `_` conjunction between. So right click and inspect on button to get the updated id and use the same with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic CSS functionality, please read up on it.

```
#lnkFirstAvailable .TimeSlotControlButton  {
  /*styles go here!*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#btnNewCustomer.TimeSlotControlButton{
background: red;
}
#btnCustomerSearch.TimeSlotControlButton{
background: green;
}
```

normaly this should work.

but i guess you are using webform(.net). runat server tag on input, changes input Id to something like that; ctl00_btnNewCustomer**. so css select doesnt work.

learn new Id's with browser inspector and change your css select with that.

Comment: Yes, Thanks A lot Man. It helps!

Answer (score 0):

try to add a second class to your button

```
        <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
            <asp:Button ID="lnkFirstAvailable" runat="server" Text="First Available Time" meta:resourcekey="lnkFirstAvailableResource" CssClass="TimeSlotControlButton grey" style="float:left;"/>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSummary" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnSummaryResource" CssClass="TimeSlotControlButton black" OnClientClick="popupSummary.Show(); return false;" />
        </div>
```

and in your css

```
.grey{
    background:grey;
}

.black{
    background:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it appears you're having difficulty using the `id` attribute, try using CSS's [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) pseudo-class like so:

```css
.TimeSlotControlButton {
  background-color: #AC2430;
  border: 2px solid #AC2430;
  color: white;
  height: 29px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv:nth-of-type(3) input {
  background-color: grey;
}

.TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv:nth-of-type(4) input {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtons">
  <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
    <input type="button" id="btnNewCustomer" value="First Button" class="TimeSlotControlButton">
  </div>
  <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
    <input type="button" id="btnCustomerSearch" value="First Button" class="TimeSlotControlButton">
  </div>
  <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
    <input type="button" id="lnkFirstAvailable" value="First Button" class="TimeSlotControlButton">

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
    <input type="button" id="btnSummary" value="First Button" class="TimeSlotControlButton">
  </div>
  <div class="TimeSlotControlBlockButtonDiv">
    <input type="button" id="lnkPreviousStep" value="First Button" class="TimeSlotControlButton">
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nth-of-type(n)

```
.TimeSlotControlBlockButtons:nth-of-type(3) input {
  background-color: grey;
}

.TimeSlotControlBlockButtons:nth-of-type(4) input {
 background-color: black;
}
```